# How to map a list of dynamically generated properties from Twilio's WhatApp for business

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, twilio

Once again asking for some help; let me explain: I've been working at integrating WhatsApp for Business to give our customers a way to send us pictures so we can process them using Azure AI.

What I've accomplished so far is to enable a Web API service as an endpoint for the Twilio's webhook and the information is flowing very nicely, the only issue I'm having is this: Twilio will connect to my Web API via web hook and do a `POST` in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, among all the `Request` parameters I need to access the list of files that are part of the message (Ref: https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#media-related-parameters).

The documentation mentions that if there is more than 1 attached file with the message it will use a zero based index to name each file, so basically it's a dynamic list of urls i need to map to an object which cannot be dynamic.

This is the `WhatsAppMessage` model:

```
public class WhatsAppMessage
{
    public string MessageSid { get; set; }
    public string AccountSid { get; set; }
    public string MessagingServiceSid { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string NumMedia { get; set; }

    public List<string> MediaList { get; set; } //from Twilio as MediaUrl{n}
}
```

This is the code I'm using to handle those posts:

```
[HttpPost("webhook")]
public IActionResult WebhookInterface([FromForm]WhatsAppMessage whatsAppMessage)
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();
    stringBuilder.Append($"Hola, dijiste '{whatsAppMessage.Body}', desde el número {whatsAppMessage.From} \n");
    int numAdjuntos = int.Parse(whatsAppMessage.NumMedia);
    stringBuilder.Append($"Hay {numAdjuntos} archivos adjuntos al mensaje. \n");

    if (numAdjuntos > 0)
    {
        // How do I access each MediaUrl{n} which are part of the Form?
        // Will be good to have a List<string> to save this urls
    }

    stringBuilder.Append($"URL de imagen: {whatsAppMessage.MediaUrl0}");

    return Ok(stringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

I know this does not sounds like a hard thing to do but I'm struggling with this! Any help will be valuable!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, it appears that your Web API may expect multiple MediaUrl and MediaContentType parameters. One solution is to use the `dynamic` type and then manually iterate with a loop if any medias exist.

Example HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/2.0
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 296

NumMedia=2&MessageSid=SMXX&SmsSid=SMXX&MediaContentType0=image/jpeg&MediaUrl0=bla.com&MediaContentType1=image/png&MediaUrl1=starwars.com
```

---

API endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("webhook")]
public IActionResult WebhookInterface([FromForm] dynamic whatsAppMessage)
{
    int numAdjuntos = whatsAppMessage.NumMedia;

    // 1st iteration: extract MediaUrl0 & MediaContentType0
    // 2nd iteration: extract MediaUrl1 & MediaContentType1 ...
    for (int i = 0; i < numAdjuntos; i++)
    {
        string mediaUrl = whatsAppMessage[$"MediaUrl{i}"];
        string mediaContentType = whatsAppMessage[$"MediaContentType{i}"];
        // ...
    
    }
}
```